# what is left for http protocol in actual web development?

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

with TLS 1.3 already in place, and around 94% of the browsers compatible with 1.2 (https://caniuse.com/#feat=tls1-2)

with certificates wittily available or even free

with amp even requesting https

**What is left for http?**

does it have any sense to spend a minute on developing under port 80 aside of a redirect?

please, do not vote negatively, this is a open question to the community, trying to figure out any real use-case for the http protocol

Comment: "please, do not vote negatively" your question is still offtopic here as not related to programming in any way.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question in fact. A good website/application is agnostic to the transport, that is the URL it is used to access it. It is at most a configuration point, and the underlying libraries handle everything related to TLS if there is a need to, but other than that what does "developing under port 80 mean"? You develop your application irrespective to what port it runs too. And even if technically you could run things off port 80 (HTTP) browsers will more and more proeminently show that as "insecure" so if you do not want to scare off your visitors...

Comment: You are not even really specifying if you are talking about more or less static websites, even with a CMS, or applications using HTTPS communication, etc.

Comment: "Open questions to the community" are not typically good stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: I know, but i neither would find a better place where asking this kind of question. Considering one or another protocol, in some way, can be seen related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, on addition: chosing features as AMP or ServiceWorkers for a web application makes it a developer decision, "developing for 80" makes those unusable, so it a web Application indeed can not be transport agnostic 100%

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, sorry i didn't specify more, indeed I was considering mostly SPAs and WPAs, event at least some AJAX functionality, everything points to https only

Comment: and everybody, sorry my English may be not so good I cannot make myself understandable without doubts

Comment: AJAX and ServiceWorkers will work exactly the same way on HTTP than HTTPS. AMP is a proprietary project/specification from Google that pushes for HTTPS on all other fronts, so obviously it will be biaised there.

Answer (score 0):

Static content, or content that we don't care it to be "stealed" or "trafficked", don't need HTTPS and still could use HTTP.

For example, you might not need HTTPS for the [`jquery.js` script](http://jquery.com) resource (or for some static logo image), at least in some *trusted* corporate Intranet. And HTTP needs less resources (both on server and on client side) than HTTPS (because no encryption occurs).

Also, in some cases, both the HTTP server and the HTTP client (the browser) is on the same local secured network, or even both running on `localhost` (perhaps your Linux laptop without network connection). Then you don't need HTTPS.
And server side HTTP libraries (like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) are slightly more complex to use with HTTPS than with HTTP.

Comment: yes, but, linking http static resources from a page https served will give you plenty of warnings and even errors depending the platform, most browsers will even not display/use the resource

Comment: Serving JavaScript over an insecure connection is, respectfully, a poor idea from the standpoint of security. There's a reason for the warnings that browsers give (since tampering with an unsecured script running on a secure page can completely invalidate the associated security guarantees)

Comment: "you might not need HTTPS for the jquery.js script" On the contrary, external injected Javascript is even more a target for HTTPS that the rest, associated with integrity protection. Otherwise your whole system security is just about at the level of the lowest secure external script you use.

Comment: Meh ... I'll buy your last paragraph but not the first two :)

Comment: I wasn't considering localhost implementation, but real production solutions. Even warnings with static images served as http.